# react-native Expo CLI gives EPERM Error : Operation not permitted for \table.xsl.tmp

Tags: react-native, expo

This happens at the start.
it looks like *.tmp (Temp files) are not accessible. How can I fix this?

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\<APP-PATH>\table.xsl.tmp'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at NodeWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\<APP-PATH>\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just make a `table.xsl.tmp` file in your project directory and rerun
> `expo start`.

This way it worked for me & [katontech](https://github.com/katontech).

However this is not the perfect solution, but this bug is tracked and discussed [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2021).

> https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2021